# Given a ring $R$, $R=(1)$ is a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

An ideal generated by the element $a$ is defined to be the intersection of all ideals containing $a$. My book says $R=(1)$ is a principal ideal, and I know how to convince myself of this using different approaches, but I can't reconcile how $R=(1)$ and $(1)$ is the intersection of all ideals containing $1$ for the following reason:
suppose I have elements $a$ and $b$, with $(a)<(b)$. They must both contain $1$, but $(1)$ can only be as large as $(a)$ which is not necessarily $R$.

Answer (score 4):

If an ideal $I$ of $R$ contains $1$, then given any $r \in R$, $r\cdot 1 \in I$. Hence $R$ is contained in $I$, and $I$ is necessarily contained in $R$, so $I=R$. So any ideal containing $1$ is in fact all of $R$, and the intersection of all such ideals is $R$. This shows $R=(1)$. Now this ideal is principal because it is generated by a single element.

Comment: but every ideal is, in particular, a subring and thus contains a 1, so how can there exist ideals not equal to R

Comment: @fenweipark Ideals are **not** subrings. (At least, not according to the definition by which a ring must have a multiplicative identity - some authors use "ring" to mean "ring, not necessarily with multiplicative identity," in which case ideals *are* subrings, but then need not contain $1$.)

Comment: @fenweipark This is a case where the analogy of ideals inside rings with normal subgroups inside groups breaks down.

Comment: so it's correct to say: any ideal containing the identity is the ring itself?

Comment: @fenweipark Yes. In fact, an ideal containing _any_ unit must contain the identity and thus be the whole ring.

Comment: @fenweipark Sure, any ideal of $R$ containing an *invertible element* of $R$ is $R$ itself.

Comment: @fenweipark You can have a proper ideal $I$ with an identity $e$ in a ring $R$ with identity $1$, and there is no contradiction. The thing is that $e$ is guaranteed to act as an identity *only on $I$*, so there's no danger of it blowing up to be all of $R$. For example, in $F\times F$, $F\times \{0\}$ is a ring with identity element $(1,0)$.